# java save list<JButton>

Tags: java, list, save

I'm having a problem creating a method to save a list of buttons in a file and then load them back into my program when it starts again. Simply put, how do I save a list into a file and then load that file back up as a list again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("filename");

ObjectOutputStream out   = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
```

Then you can use

```
out.writeObject(ArrayOfObjects[i]);
```

to save an element to the file. You will have to iterate over all elements of the list.

EDIT: I dont't know whether it is possible to use something like

```
out.writeObject(TheWholeList)
```

But you should definitely try it .

Comment: I've tried to write the whole list as an object but the problem is when I try to read it back in and fill a list...